# chatRoomDidChangeOnlineUsers does not remove user after leaveRoom

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have a chatRoom with a bunch of users in it. When one of the users leaves, `chatRoomDidChangeOnlineUsers` does get called, but the user who left still shows up in the `onlineUsers` array. Here is how I have the other user leaving the room. (I even logout the user to see if it changes anything, but it does not.)

```
[[QBChat instance] leaveRoom:myRoom];
[[QBChat instance] logout];
[presenceTimer invalidate]; //the timer that sends the [QBChat instance] presence
```

**So is the delegate not supposed to show the user who currently left?** It works fine when users join the room.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does

Here could be an issue with [[QBChat instance] leaveRoom:myRoom];

Are you sure that **myRoom** is not nil?

Try to print  **myRoom** to log and do only [[QBChat instance] leaveRoom:myRoom]; without logout

Comment: `myRoom` is certainly not nil, I get its name and JID when the delegate is called, and also in `chatRoomDidEnter`. I just want to clarify, the delegate `chatRoomDidChangeOnlineUsers` does get called when another user leaves the room, it's just the `onlineUsers` list that is not updated.

Comment: Do you think I can work around this by manually requesting room users after `chatRoomDidChangeOnlineUsers` gets called? By that I just mean explicitly asking for the online users, `[[QBChat instance] requestRoomOnlineUsers:myRoom]` so that I could just get the most updated online users

Comment: I did try the above but since I use custom nicknames, `requestRoomOnlineUsers:` returns 0 for every user instead of their userID (which shows if I do not use a custom nickname). Is that supposed to happen?